# Set `UIImage` to `UITextview.textColor`

Tags: ios, uitextview

What i want is to set `UIImage` to `UITextview.textColor`.

So is that possible that : If i set clear Color to `textColor` and set image to `UITextView's` background. Now i want to set clear color to `UITextview` except string area so that image is set to text background.??

Comment: Looking for [`ClearTextLabel`](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/cleartextlabel) ?

Comment: yes but how to clear background color except string area. ?

Answer (score 0):

Use this method

```
[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Something.png"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set an Image as the `backgroundColor` of the `UITextView` like this:

```
txtView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ImageName.png"]];
```

All the best!!!